# Running DOS commands from Vbscript .Help needed with HTA

Tags: user-interface, automation, vbscript, sap-gui

I have a vbscript that calls another from within itself. It works fine wen I run it from command line with cscript. For example the master vbscript has a code such as

```
cmd /k cd "Path having the vbs" && cscript "slave_temp.vbs"
```

Now I have an HTA where the master vbscript resides when I click on a button on the HTA this command is executed to call the slave.vbs

This is the command I use to call the slave.vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
runpath = "cmd.exe /K"& Chr(32) &"cd " & Chr(34)&final_path&Chr(34)&Chr(32)&Chr(38)&Chr(38)& Chr(32)& "cscript " &Chr(34)&Name1 &"_temp.vbs"&Chr(34)
objShell.Run runpath
```

Here `final_path` has the path name and Name1 has the file name of the slave.

I tried checking out the runpath value using Msgbox and it seemed all fine. But I don't understand why this doesn't work.

On a final note, the slave.vbs has SAP GUI automation code and it throws this error when I use HTA to trigger.

> C:\path of slave\slave_temp.vbs(2, 4) (null): Invalid syntax

But the file executes properly when the slave_temp.vbs is executed separately. What can be the problem here.?  Does this mean SAP objects don't have support wen run from HTA ?...

Help is much appreciated.

The following are the first few lines of the slave_temp.vbs having the SAP automation code

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
```

Sorry for the long question. But I think the issue is when calling SAP GUI object from HTA. Kindly help me tackle this.

Comment: `Set SapGuiAuto  = WScript.GetObject("SAPGUI")`. Read [GetObject Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ywk619w(v=vs.84).aspx) in _Reference (Windows Script Host)_. And  `"SAPGUI"` should be the fully qualified path name of the file that contains the object persisted to disk?

Comment: So your `slave_temp.vbs` script is being executed then? Or not? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Bond it works if i run it separately via a cmd prompt. doesnt work when i call from HTA. But i still couldn figureout the fact that i cant use the SAPGUI object even when i run it under WSH. Suprisingly if i hardcode the slave_temp.vbs into the hta environment and invoke it via button click. it works cause HTA imports libraries to support SAPGUI. So thats how im making it to work. But the question still stands why am i not able to run the vbs containg the SAPGUI object from a WSH shell ?